# Is there a way to get make a css grid element stretch to a certain size but also behave like it has justify-self set to end?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have two elements inside a grid container. Each element has a max-width of let's say 200px. I want the first element to stretch to fill the cell up to 200px, but also stick to the right border of its cell. This is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="element__1"></div>
  <div class="element__2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 2.5vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

.element__1 {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 50px;
  /* justify-self: end; */
}

.element__2 {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

This satisfies the condition of stretching to fill the cell up to 200px, however the gap appears much larger since the element by default sticks to the left cell border.

Comment: "however the gap appears much larger since the element by default sticks to the left cell border." Yes, this would indeed happen – this is how spacing and geometry works. What is your desired outcome?

Comment: @Wongjn The extra space inside the grid cell of element__1 shall be on the left side of element__1 instead of the right. As if justify-self: end. However, still want to retain the stretch functionality (element__1 will grow to fit the grid cell up until it reaches 200px).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand – why can't you use `justify-self: end`?

Comment: @Wongjn because `justify-self: end` would give element__1 a fixed length of 40px. It should also stretch to fill its cell until it reaches 200px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider applying `width: 100%` to `.element__1` so that it stretches in width as much as it can, until it hits the `max-width` constraint. This should allow you to use `justify-self: end`:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 2.5vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

.element__1 {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 50px;
  justify-self: end;
}

.element__2 {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="element__1"></div>
  <div class="element__2"></div>
</div>
```